# Freezing traditional Greek dishes

Tags: freezing

I cook many authetic Greek dishes for Greek Easter. This year I have very little time to prepare. Can I make dishes like Moussaka, Dolmades, Spanakopita in advance and freeze them?

Comment: Moussaka and Spanakopita freeze like a charm; dolmades, hmm, not certain (because of the grape leaves)

Answer (score 5):

Moussaka freezes fine, some would say it improves the flavor, and shouldn't damage the texture.

Spanakopita I would not freeze whole, you will likely lose all the crispness and texture from the pastry. You could make the filling in advance though, and then put the pastry on the thawed filling on the day and bake it. Just be sure the filling is completely thawed, and getting close to room temperature. Also, freezing may force water out of the filling, drain it out before you bake or it could get soggy.

Dolmades I'm not sure, I would expect they'd freeze fine, although you may get some sogginess. I'll defer this to another answer.

Comment: I worked at a Greek restaurant where we rolled the dolmades and froze them raw, then cooked them off a couple times a day. They froze fine.

Comment: It also occurs to me that we did the spanakopita ahead of time too. We did individual portions, baked them very light, and then crisped them in a convection oven to serve.

Comment: You can actually buy frozen spanakopita, too, so it must be possible!

Answer (score 2):

I have put cooked Dolmades in the freezer on three different occasions because they are time consuming and I create a large batch each time. They need to be wrapped tight anyway and they came out just right. I heat them in the oven and once had left over (also frozen)  egg lemon soup (afgolemono) another time just some additional lemon water and another left over chicken boulian gravy. Idea is to serve them moist and not dry.In fact I think I will try microwaving them in future.

Answer (score 1):

Today I made 6 dozen beef/lamb/rice dolmades cooked in beef broth/oliveoil and lemon juice. I placed waxed paper on a large baking tray, laid out dolmades to freeze and when frozen the next day, zip lock them loosely and put back in freezer. When wanting whatever number, remove individually frozen dolmades, thaw and enjoy . Works every time :)